# How to get the LBA ranges, given a file?

Tags: c, windows, ntfs

Given a file, how can I get the LBA ranges corresponding to the file?
Can FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS do the job?

Comment: @gariepy: other way around.. that question is a duplicate of this. I asked this question on 2010-10-06. I got an answer on 2011-04-11, and I selected it as an answer. The duplicate question was asked on 2013-02-18, more than 2 years after my question. and almost 2 years after the answer was posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364572%28VS.85%29.aspx), it will help you.  Note that if you're trying to get down lower, you might need a littlemore; the file system thinks in clusters, for example, while you may not be thinking in clusters).